# Custom header not working as expected using fancyheader

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to have a custom header like the following: 
Chapitre5 (Chapter5) in the left and the name of the chapter in the right(Mise en oeuvre)
[image]

I used this in my root .tex file:

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

```
\pagestyle{fancy}

%clears header & footer
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\rhead{\leftmark}
\lhead{
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
        \chaptername \thechapter
    \fi
}
```

But it doesn't  take into account unnumbered chapters after the first chapter, i.e `\thechapter`>0. So when i add a chapter with `\chapter*{annexe}` right after chapter5, i get the same header as in the picture and **i expect it** to be **empty in the left** and have the chapter name *annexe* in the right side of the header.
Can you, please, tell me how to do it? explaining what the code does would be very nice. As i am actually new to Latex.

Comment: I am not sure you need to redefine anything. What is *mise en oevre*? a chapter heading? Can you make the example compilable, so that it is easier to see where what is coming from?

Comment: @Johannes_B *mise en oeuvre* is actually the name of the chapter.

Comment: I forgot to give you a link, in there you can find which details we need to know. I am still a bit clueless on what you really want.

Comment: i want to have a header like the one in the picture : in the left side **Chapter X** where X is the number of the chapter and the **name of the chapter** in the right side

Comment: The rest of the question is an attempt that didn't work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the left field with `\hfill` in between the two parts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % mock text

\pagestyle{fancy}

%clears header & footer
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[L]{\chaptername\ \thechapter\hfill\leftmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Mise en oeuvre}

\kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For managing unnumbered chapters, you can patch the `\chapter` command and add the “Chapter n” bit only if a condition is satisfied.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % mock text

\pagestyle{fancy}

%clears header & footer
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[L]{%
  \insertchaptername\hfill\leftmark
}
\newcommand{\insertchaptername}{%
  \ifstarredchapter
  \else
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
      \chaptername\ \thechapter
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newif\ifstarredchapter
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\chapter{\global\starredchapterfalse}{}{}
\pretocmd\@schapter{\global\starredchaptertrue\chaptermark{#1}}{}{}
\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo % we do the \chaptermark
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\kant[1-10]

\chapter{Mise en oeuvre}

\kant[11-20]

\chapter*{Annexe}

\kant[21-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you try it with an un-numbered chapter `\chapter*{conclusion}` after this chapter, it would have the old header

Comment: And if you add it before it would have **Chapter 0** !

Comment: @Lelouch It's quite easy to manage it. Stay tuned.

Comment: That worked for un-named chapters in the end. But i couldn't get rid of **Chapter 0** in list of figures. Any clues?

Comment: @Lelouch Fixed.